# Numerical problems with qnorm

Tags: r, precision, numeric, norm

I'm having a numeric issue using `qnorm(psn())`. The problem is numeric.

Firstly, the Skew-Normal CDF round the result, since `psn(9)` is not `1`:

```
 library(sn)
 psn(9)
#[1] 1
```

then

```
 qnorm(psn(9))
#[1] Inf
```

And see that:

```
 qnorm(.9999999999999999)
#[1] 8.209536
 qnorm(.99999999999999999)
#[1] Inf
```

note that `8.209536` is not that big, so this rounding is very imprecise.

Then, my final problem is the calculation of `qnorm(psn())`, that is part of my Copula density. Any hint on how can I avoid these numerical problems?

Answer (score 1):

(This is not a resolution to your dilemma, more of an explanation of why I think you're seeing this and perhaps not likely to find an easy solution.)

I think this is getting into the realm where normal floating-point precision isn't going to work for you. For instance, doing the inverse of your function:

```r
options(digits=22)
pnorm(8.209536)
# [1] 0.99999999999999989
pnorm(8.209536) - 1
# [1] -1.1102230246251565e-16
```

which is very close to

```r
.Machine$double.eps
# [1] 2.2204460492503131e-16
```

which, according to `?.Machine`, is

```
double.eps: the smallest positive floating-point number 'x' such that
          '1 + x != 1'.  It equals 'double.base ^ ulp.digits' if either
          'double.base' is 2 or 'double.rounding' is 0; otherwise, it
          is '(double.base ^ double.ulp.digits) / 2'.  Normally
          '2.220446e-16'.
```

It might be possible to translate what you need into higher-precision using auxiliary packages like [`gmp`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gmp/) or [`Rmpfr`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rmpfr/). (I don't know if they support `qnorm`-like operations.)